# Can an internal load balancer be deployed to one subnet? (AWS Cloud)

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elb

I see AWS Cloud load balancers in 2 categories:

**By Traffic** - Internet and Internal LBs

**By Use** - Application, Network and CLassic LBs

I want to deploy an **internal load balancer into one private subnet** and ask it to only distribute traffic among the instances in that subnet.
Is that possible?

I know that application LBs must be deployed to 2 subnets. Is there a configuration that allows deployment to only one subnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that application LBs must be deployed to 2 subnets.  Is there a configuration that allows deployment to only one subnet?

Unfortunately, **not for ALB**.

However, you can use **1 subnet with NLB and CLB**.